# Altium: keep out joins to through hole pads

Tags: altium

I have a keep out on the bottom layer that covers a heat dissipation plane. I don't want traces here, as I want the plane to be effective at dissipating the heat.

Keep out main properties:

- Restricted for Layer: Bottom Layer
- Keepout Restrictions: Track

The issue is that I have a through hole component on this area, that is routed on the top layer. The keep out is preventing a clearance area around the THT pads, effectively shorting them to the plane.

Illustration of the issue:

[image]

As it is, it seems that the keepout creates a copper pad that is overlayed on the region, besides preventing the auto-router from entering it.

## EDIT:

Curiously, in the 3D view the copper seems correctly managed, even with the keepout:

[image]

What happens is that the clearance area is there, but because the keepout is blue (placed on the bottom layer) you can't see it.

So, my question becomes: **Doesn't the keepout participate in the bottom copper layer, despite the fact that it shows as blue?**

Comment: Don't use the autorouter.

Comment: How did you define the keep-out area?  Is it a fill that covers the bottom layer?  I would normally opt to use keep-out 'lines' to manage where tracks are allowed, not fills (unless I would like to void an _unoccupied_ region).

Comment: To see what the layer will look like, select it and type shift-S, to cycle through normal, layer + dimmed, layer alone. And double check it in a Gerber viewer before production, of course.

Comment: What do you mean by "participate" in the bottom copper layer?  There are view settings that let you adjust transparencies for different types of items,  which should let you visually distinguish the keepout from the polygon.